# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, configuration, migration

I have created **OnModelCreating** method in **ApplicationDbContext** class but i can't set the **MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion** class because **Configuration** type couldn't be found. What would be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `Enable-Migrations` command from the package manager console. Running this command will create the `Configuration` class in the `Migrations` folder.

Please check this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) for a detaild walk-through on setting up Code-First Migrations.